# pl/sql - compare record counts across 2 user's tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, count

I have table 'stf_table' under the schema 'staff' with username 'staff'.

I have table 'emp_table' under the schema 'employee' with username 'employee'.

Both of these are under the same database SID/host/port but user 'staff' doesn't have privelege to query tables under schema 'employee' and vice versa (ie. user 'employee' doesn't have privelege to query tables under schema 'staff'). But each user can query the table under their own schema. Note: I cannot grant extra privileges and I don't want to have to dump both tables into a local schema.

Is it possible to write a PL/SQL proc or package that would do the following?

```
 select count(*) from stf_table;
 select count(*) from emp_table;
```

then output both counts to a file (ie a .txt or .dat not concerned) like so:

```
stf_table count: 47830
emp_table count: 36462
difference: 11368
counts match: FALSE
```

Comment: One way to do that is to create a connection to one schema under the other schema provided that you have the password for it. Then you may refer to the tables from the other schema by using the `connation_name.Schema_name.Table_name`

Comment: @Ahmad-San - if you had posted that as an answer I would have voted it down, because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: can be done at the command line what Operating System do you use ?

Comment: @Toop - any question which is predicated on not being able to grant additional privileges invites the pushback "Why not?"  So, what is the deal here?  Why are you looking for a way to subvert the security model?  Why introduce potential backdoors into your application instead of taking the easy path?  In short, what constraints prevent you making additional grants and/or creating additional objects to minimise the impact?

Comment: @Toop - Other questions.  How often does this diff query need to be run?  Does it have to be run by STAFF and EMPLOYEE?  What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @APC. I can't get the grants - I've asked the DBA and they've said no. I'm not trying to subvert security - I can access these tables one at a time so why not figure a way to automatically compare them. I might be able to create additional objects. The diff might be run every day. The employee vs. staff table is a little contrived I will be using the same kind of method for a range of source and target tables. Purpose is reducing test effort.

Comment: @Toop - unfortunately some DBAs over-emphasize their role as gatekeepers and forget that the most important thing is providing their users with access to the data *they* need.   If this is actually a test system then their oduracy is even more perplexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granting permissions is the correct thing to do however as you state this is not possible:

one solution could be to do it at the command line using scripts.
(the biggest drawback is the username & password would be embedded in the script for all to see, so make sure the scripts are appropriately secured)

first create 2 scripts:

a.sql:

```
set timing off
set feedback off
set pages 0
select count(*) from stf_table;
exit
```

b.sql:

```
set timing off
set feedback off
set pages 0
select count(*) from emp_table;
exit
```

now create a script file extract.bat to get the output:

```
 @echo off
 FOR /F "usebackq delims=!" %%i IN (`sqlplus -s username/password@db_a @a.sql`) DO set resulta=%%i 

 FOR /F "usebackq delims=!" %%i IN (`sqlplus -s username/password@db_b @b.sql`) DO set resultb=%%i 

 set /a diff=%resulta%-%resultb%

 echo stf_table count %resulta% 
 echo emp_table count %resultb%
 echo difference %diff%

 IF %diff%=0 (
 echo Counts match TRUE
 ) ELSE (
 echo Counts match FALSE)
```

now simply execute `extract.bat` at the command prompt

Comment: So, instead of granting limited privileges on a pair of tables to two accounts you propose exposing total access to both schemas to anybody who has access to the server?  Really?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the people who need this information may not have access to the server.  Plus the problem of keeping script in sync when the schema password changes.

Comment: There is no mention in the question how the solution is to be used, also why do you assume the script will be stored on a publicly accessable file store ?

Comment: How do you suggest I secure them?

Comment: Put them on a file system that is permissioned for just the people who need to run it (if there is auditing turned on too thats an added bonus). if this was a daily job you could lock it down to a single user and copy the output to a public location perhaps?

Comment: @Kevin - my assumption was that the users who need this access would not be people who already have access to the server (otherwise they  would probably be able to get the data already i.e. they're DBAs).  I agree that might be an unwarranted assumption, and I agree that access to the script can be policed.  It just seems like an unnecessarily convoluted and insecure solution.

Comment: @APC The OS can lock down the files, so security should not be a concern, it has to be better than no solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to grant additional privileges to either user, you don't have many options.

You can create a procedure owned by a super user, say an account which has SELECT ANY TABLE, (but *not* SYS or SYSTEM) which does both counts and calculates the difference.

```
create function get_diff 
    return pls_integer
    authid definer
as 
    c1 pls_integer;
    c2 pls_integer;
begin
    select count(*) 
    into c1
    from staff.stf_table;
    select count(*)
    into c2
    from employee.emp_table;

    return abs(c1-c2);
end get_diff;
/
```

So the crucial thing here is the AUTHID DEFINER.  That means the function runs with the permissions of the user who owns the function; because they have the neecssary permissions to query both tables that user can run the function, and so can any other user to whom they grant `EXECUTE ON GET_DIFF`.

That really is the minimum about of granting you can get away with.

---

NB: I haven't addressed the question of writing to a file, because I don't really think that's the thrust of your question.  The main thing is permissions.

---

> "Is there no way that the proc could connect as user 'staff' save the
>   count to a file. then connect as user 'employee' save the count to the
>   same file and compare?"

No.  That's not the way the security model works.

STAFF's data is owned by STAFF and EMPLOYEE's data is owned by EMPLOYEE.  By default, STAFF cannot see EMPLOYEE's data and vice versa.  To change this situation you have two options:

1. Have STAFF grant SELECT on their table to EMPLOYEE and have EMPLOYEE grant SELECT on their table to STAFF.
2. Use an account which has privileges on both schemas' tables to do the work.

Obviously, there may well be data protection issues with the first approach.  If that is your concern there are some refinements open to you:

1. Have each schema own a view which just selects a count of their records, and grant privileges on the views.
2. If you have Enterprise Edition 10gR2 or higher, you can use column-level VPD: grant select on the table put put a policy in place to hide all the sensitive data.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/network.101/b10773/apdvcntx.htm#1008486).

Comment: I really don't have a superuser. Is there no way that the proc could connect as user  'staff'  save the count to a file. then connect as user  'employee' save the count to the same file and compare?

Comment: @toop - the procedure has to be owned by somebody.  And that somebody needs to have the necessary permissions on both schemas' tables.

Answer (score 1):

APC is right in that you can't solve this problem easily without granting additional permissions. There might be a simpler way than what he is suggesting.

I would suggest creating a view and granting access to that view to the other schema.

In the STAFF schema you can create a view stf_table_count:

```
create or replace view stf_table_count
as
select count(*) as num_rows
from stf_count;
```

Then grant select on that view to the employee schema:

```
grant select on stf_table_count to employee;
```

Then from the employee schema you can find the result without getting the data

```
select num_rows from staff.stf_table_count
union all
select count(*) from emp_table;
```

You can also repeat this process to get the employee counts in the staff schema.

I'm not really an Oracle database security expert so your mileage may vary on this answer but I think it should work.

Comment: This is basically one of the workarounds I suggested when I updated my answer yesterday.